# Google usage limits - explanation

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, matrix, distance

Google Distance Matrix say:

```
Usage Limits

Each query sent to the Distance Matrix API is limited by the number of allowed elements, where the number of origins times the number of destinations defines the number of elements.

The Distance Matrix API has the following limits in place:

100 elements per query.
100 elements per 10 seconds.
2 500 elements per 24 hour period.
Google Maps API for Business customers have higher limits:

625 elements per query.
1 000 elements per 10 seconds.
100 000 elements per 24 hour period.
Maps API for Business customers can purchase additional quota by contacting their Google Enterprise Sales Account Manager.

Distance Matrix API URLs are restricted to 2048 characters, after URL encoding. As some Distance Matrix API service URLs may involve many locations, be aware of this limit when constructing your URLs.
```

I want to know on an example:

is this limit per user on my site or completly all user share this limits, so
If I have 100 users a site at same time and 10 users click in same seconds to get DIstanceMatrix did I get OVER_QUERY_LIMIT ... or this is per user

Please explain me that. I'm really confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This answer is more an assumption than based on official facts:**

When you send a serverside request, the only detail that may be detected by the  target-server is the REMOTE_ADDRESS, the IP of the server that sends the request.

Therefore(assuming you didn't authenticate the request in any manner), this limit can't be set for:

- a domain(different domains may share a single IP, it's not possible to reliable detect the domain )
- a user (the IP of the user will not be forwarded to google)

So this limit can only apply to a server, therefore this assumption must be correct:

*so If I have 100 users a site at same time and 10 users click in same seconds to get DIstanceMatrix did I get OVER_QUERY_LIMIT*

...furthermore: the 10 users must not be on your site(domain), when there is another domain hosted on the same server where also are serverside scripts that request the DistanceMatrixService at the same time, this should also apply to the limits.

I know, it somewhow sounds crazy, but for me that's the only logical conclusion.

---

Related to the Distance Matrix Service of the Maps-Javascript-API:

The only clearly [defined limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#usage_limits_and_requirements) are:

- Maximum of 25 origins or 25 destinations per request; and
- At most 100 elements (origins times destinations) per request.

The additional note: *Requests are also rate limited. If too many elements are requested within a certain time period, an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT response code will be returned.* is really  vague. I've tested it and don't receive any error with dozens of requests(each with 100 elements) within a second, so the rate-limits for the  Distance Matrix API(100 elements per 10 seconds and
2 500 elements per 24 hour period) it appears not to apply to the Distance Matrix Service of the Maps-Javascript-API.

Comment: But all my code is clent side I dont have connection with database

Comment: The limits you've cited in you question apply to the Distance Matrix API, not to the Distance Matrix Service of the Maps-Javascript-API (client-side requests)

Comment: No, I want to use DistanceMatrixService

Comment: For the placesService/Places API AFAIK exists only a limit per day, so you shouldn't have any problems

Comment: @Dr.Molle Hi, How can I increase 25 destinations to 100? Because I need distance of 70 records at a time...Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google terms](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq#js_usage_limits),

> Requests that constitute page views are applied against the total number of page views

So the page view is important, but not the number of users.
If you have 100 users at the same time generating 10.000 page views, you have used 10.000 queries and you quota is decremented by 10.000